# Redirecting users after an action

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am trying to achieve having a redirection if the user logs in successfully. I was trying to  call `this.$router.push('/profile')` with then the call back after login however I get an error stating `Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$router')` I am not sure if there is a new flow to how to get this done since I am using composition with `<script setup>` syntax. I read the document reference online but still not seeing anything concrete as to how to do this type of navigation now. How can I achieve this with the new vue3 composition api? It seems I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `setup()` inside the script, you can't access the router with $router.
if you use vue3, this code can help you:

```
<script>
import { defineComponen } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()
    function login() {
     router.push('/profile')
    }
    return {
      login
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: I see, so my approach was wrong, this granted me some more clarity in the situation. Thanks